# how to generate other class file besides R.java?

Tags: android

As you can see from the project below, I want to know how to generate the java file in the gen folder:

[image: Example image]

Comment: Why do you need the class files from these auto-generated Java files?

Comment: These are auto generated files if there's no error in your program they are generated themselves.

Comment: This is a old project which my boss give to me,I want to know why there are other files in the gen folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create R.java

In order for the application source code to be able to access the resources within the res/ directory, a class called R.java (for Resources) is created.

Use the Android Asset Packaging Tool (aapt) to create the R.java file:

```
ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/aapt
                    package
                    -v
                    -f
                    -m
                    -S DEV_HOME/res
                    -J DEV_HOME/src
                    -M DEV_HOME/AndroidManifest.xml
                    -I ANDROID_HOME/platforms/android-7/android.jar
```

[Building Android programs on the command line](http://geosoft.no/development/android.html)